# Array setup throwing errors on initiation - CS0021 Error (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I wanted to practice making arrays by creating a small program that would allow the user to enter a number of elements an array would have, then create a array with the amount of elements the user has entered, and fill all elements with numbers. For ex.: If you type 3, it would generate 3 elements, fill element 1 with number 1 and number 2 with number 2 and so on. Although I get a specific error every time: CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'
Here is my code:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num;
        string getNum;
        getNum = Console.ReadLine();
        num = Int32.Parse(getNum);
        int[] array = new int[num];
        Console.WriteLine("Array created with {0} elements.",num);
    }
    static void Array(int input)
    {
        int num = 1;
        int inum = input;
        while(inum >= input)
        {
            Array[inum] = num;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",input);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", num);
            inum = inum - 1;
            num = num + 1;
        }
```

Thanks in advance if you decide to help me out :)

Comment: `Array` is resolved to the name of your method `void Array(int input)`. What are you trying to do? Your method `Array` doesn't have any array to work with.

Comment: hm, I just realized I shouldn't have asked. Been mindboggled for a long time, does it error because I declared array and used Array? (Notice the caps)
EDIT: No. It doesn't, that's not the reason.

Comment: Also, what I am trying to do is i am trying to give it numbers into elements. int[] array = new int[num]; declares a array with a specific amount of elements... and array[inum] = num; is supposed to give numbers to those elements. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your prgoram `Array` is a method.

Therefore the line `Array[inum] = num` is erroring as `Array` is a method, and you cannot apply an indexer (`[]`) to a method.

The quickest way to achieve what you want it something like the following:

```
static int[] Array(int input) // Change return type to return an array of integers
{
    var result = new int[input]; // Declare a local variable to hold a new array of size input.

    // Change while to basic for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        result[inum] = i + 1; // set elements of the result array.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",input);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
    }
}
```

In your main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num;
    string getNum;
    getNum = Console.ReadLine();
    num = Int32.Parse(getNum);
    int[] array = Array(num); // Change this to call the Arrra(int num) method
    Console.WriteLine("Array created with {0} elements.",num);
}
```

Or else you could use a simple Linq statement:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, input).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets tidy up your code a little, and try to make it do what you seem to want it to do:

Lets start by getting out any logic from you `Main` method, and writing specific methods that take small steps towards your goal. Remember, the smaller you make your methods, the harder you will find it to write a bug. If you are learning, start absurdly small and grow bigger as you gain confidence.

Ok, there is the concept of asking a user for a number, let's write a method that does this, and make it as robust as possible in the process. Remember, users are dumb! Ask for a number, and they'll type anything but:

```
public static int PromptUserForPositiveInteger(string prompt)
{
    int number;
    Console.Write(prompt);
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!int.TryParse(input, out number) ||
             number < 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Input is not a valid number, try again: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return number;
}
```

Ok, so what this method does is ask the user for a postive integer, and it will keep doing that until the user manages to enter a valid number or pulls the plug. Either way, we are safe. `int.TryParse` is a safe way to extract an `int` out of a `string`; if its possible to do so, it will give you a number and return `true`, otherwise it will return `false`. What it won't do is blow up in your face if it fails, something that `int.Parse` is rather happy to do. Avoid `Parse` like plague, always use the frendlier `TryParse`.

Also worth mentioning, this method is an *implementation detail*, so its `private`. No one outside your class needs to use it, so don't show it.

Notice also that we can generalize this making the caller specify how you want to prompt the user. There is no reason why you'd want to constraint this method only to array sizes, maybe tomorrow you need the number of bananas your are going to feed the monkey! Whenever its cheap and easy, generalize your code. Whenever generalizing is hard, don't, odds are you probably wont need it and its wasted effort.

Now, the next task we need is to make an `int` array and fill it up with values. The value will be the index of each array element. Oh but wait, we said we'd make a method per task no matter how absurdly small! Yeah, I know, but absurdly small only goes so far.

```
private static int[] CreatArrayAndSetValuesToIndex(int size)
{
    Debug.Assert(size >= 0);
    var array = new int[size];

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return array;
}
```

`CreatArrayAndSetValuesToIndex` might seem an absurdly long name, but it tells you *exactly what the method does*. Get used to using descriptive names and avoid abbreviations. Nowdays with intellisense there is no point in using short enigmatic names.

Also notice the argument validation. I'll never stress this out enough:*always validate inputs to your methods!*. If things aren't supposed to work under certain conditions, make sure you are doing everything possible to avoid these conditions. Because the method is private, `Debug.Assert` is enough. If it were part of the public surface, you'd need to throw an appropiate exception (`ArgumentOutOfRange` comes to mind as an apt one).

Last but not least, let's write ourselves one last method that prints out `int` arrays so that we can make sure our code is working well:

```
private static void PrintOut(int[] array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array);
}
```

I've taken advantage here of tools already available in the framework. `string.Join` is a nifty little method that takes any enumerable object (arrays are one of them) and creates a string of all its members with a given separator, in this case, new line.

And now, all thats left is putting it all together:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var size = PromptUserForPositiveInteger("Enter array size: ");
    var array = CreatArrayAndSetValuesToIndex(size);
    PrintOutArray(array);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And we're done!